# Prove this $\int_0^\infty\int_0^1\frac{1}{r}(1-3x^2)e^{-r(1-x^2)}dx dr=-\frac{2}{3}$ or disprove

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

Is this true
$$\int_0^\infty\int_0^1\frac{1}{r}(1-3x^2)e^{-r(1-x^2)}dx dr=-\frac{2}{3}$$
or the integral diverges?

Comment: Just use Integration by parts.